# How to diagnose a duplicated fuzzy image on one laptop screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, video, graphics-card

I have an older dell laptop that has suddenly gone from displaying the full resolution to showing the screen twice, almost like in widescreen mode, one on top of each other.  They are very fuzzy, yet I can kind of still see what is going on as I navigate through Windows.

I've tried installing the latest video drivers, but the dell site doesn't have any for Windows 7 (even though it was working fine when I first got it).  I assume it's a hardware thing but I hope I can be proven wrong.

Comment: Do you mean that you see the same picture twice, once on the top half and once on the bottom half?

Answer (score 0):

Is display ok before/while booting to windows?

You can boot another OS, like Ubuntu. It's easy to create bootable USB flash drive, just download [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), run, select Ubuntu distribution and proper drive letter. You should 
format the flash drive to FAT32 first.

Then boot your laptop from this flash, you will see if the issue is hardware related.

Comment: No, its cloned as soon as I boot up.  :\

Comment: So you properly shutdown your laptop, turned on, and the screen was fuzzy immediately as you hit the power button, right? Well, not good. At most, you can connect external monitor and see if the issue is in graphics card itself, or laptop display.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen us fine during boot while you see the initial BIOS messages and goes fuzzy after Windows boots then your resolution settings are set wrong.  See if you can get to them in safe mode.  That or something went wrong in your video drivers.  Try and remove in safe mode and you will come up in low res mode.  Then you can look for better drivers.